# How to see the intermediate code on compilation of a C program?

Tags: compiling, c

I want to see the intermediate code generated during the compilation of a `C` program.
Using the `-S` flag, the object code is generated  but is there anything to see the `.i` files, called as intermediate code.

Comment: have you tried $cat filename.i ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is `gcc`* you also need `-save-temps` after `-S`

 `gcc -S -save-temps file.cpp` would make `file.i`

---

***** By default, `gcc` is installed and linked to `cc`. If you install another **C** Compiler, `cc` will link to that.